# Ajuda com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho 2 tabelas;

```
[links]
id
link
clicks

Exemplo de Link cadastrado
ID     link                       clicks
1      http://www.google.com.br   NULL    
2      http://www.gmail.com       NULL   

[users]
id
nome
email

Exemplo de user cadastrado
ID      NOME           EMAIL
400     XXXXXXXXX      XXXX@XXXX.com
100     AAAAAAAAAA     AAAAA@AAAAA.com
250     DDDDDDDDD      DDDDDD@DDDDD.com
```

Quando o usuário clica em um link, ele seta que aquele id do usuário clicou la, adicionando o id dentro do campo "clicks", ficando:

```
ID     link                       clicks
1      http://www.google.com.br   400
```

Se outro clicar também no mesmo link, fica assim:

```
ID     link                       clicks
1      http://www.google.com.br   400, 250
```

Se outro clicar novamente no mesmo link, fica assim:

```
ID     link                       clicks
1      http://www.google.com.br   400, 250, 100
```

E assim com os demais links etc.

O que eu preciso é via PHP e MySQL saber por exemplo, todos que clicaram no link gooogle.com.br mostrando o nome e o email dele.

Sinceramente não estou conseguindo pensar na estrutura do código e lógica.

Comment: Seria melhor criar outra tabela, por exemplo `links_click`, ao clicar salvar nesta tabela o código do link, código do usuário, data e horário do clique e etc, e quando quiser saber quem clicou basta fazer uma consulta nesta tabela fazendo o join com link e users.

Comment: Sim, mas o sistema ja existe, não posso alterar agora....

Comment: @Roberta Tire um tempinho para avaliar as resposta que os colegas deram as suas [Perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/75085/roberta?tab=questions) . Se a resposta ajudou de alguma forma Vote , se resolveu seu problema aceite ✔️.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa relacionar em outra tabela os cliques, pode ser apenas os ids, dos users x links, desta forma ficará simples trabalhar com os dados.

Entretanto, se vc observar o field clicks, os dados inseridos estão/são um array. voce pode manipular esse array para obter os dados separados. É bem fácil trabalhar com arrays, dá uma olhada aqui

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

faça um looping foreach para cada array, dessa forma vc consegue obter os valores individuais.

Answer (score 0):

```
select clicks from links where link = "http://www.gmail.com";

$clicks= explode(",",$row->clicks);
for($x=0;$x<count($clicks);$x++){
$sql = "select nome, email from users where id = ".$clicks[$x];
}
```

Não desenvolvi a lógica toda.
Mas assim resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer a consulta a seguir:

```
select * from users where find_in_set
(id, 
    (
        select clicks from links where id = 1 /*id do link que deseja consultar*/
    )
);
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92e162/1)**

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria você criar uma nova tabela para tratar essa questão.
Mas da forma que você está fazendo, já vi fazerem muito similar para geração de relatórios usando json_encode e o json_decode.